# Lipschitz Continuity of function with sumstructure

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity

I wonder if for a function with a sum structure $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, f(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n f_i(x)$ that is Lipschitz continous in the sense that $$\| f(x)-f(y)\| \leq L\|x-y\| $$ for some $L>0$ and $\forall x,y$,  **all partial sums $f_s(x)=\frac{1}{s}\sum_i^s f_i(x),\: s=1,...,n$ are also lipschitz continous**?
I have tried splitting $f$ up into the to sums from 1 to s and s+1 to n in the above definition of Lipschitz continuity. This could be bounded above(!) by the triangle inequality but I would need to find a lower bound to ensure the Lipschitz continuity.

Thanks for your help!

Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any function that is not Lipschitz continous on $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example $f(x,y) = e^x$. Define $f_1(x,y) = f(x,y)$, $f_2(x,y) = -f(x,y)$. Then $\frac{1}{2}(f_1(x,y) + f_2(x,y)) = 0$ is Lipschitz continous, but the partial sum $f_1(x,y) = e^x$ isn't.

Comment: good point, thanks!